# Input date validation while typing the date yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am trying to block the user to enter invalid numbers. I am currently supporting the years from `1901` to `20XX`. So for example when the user is trying to enter the year from either 2 or 1 should be fine in the first letter but not 3. In the second character, a user can enter 9 or 0 and they shouldn't enter 3 or 4, etc. this is my current implementation but it's blocking from the first character because it's checking for the entire string at once.

```
                   <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    sx={{ pr: 3 }}
                    value={dateOfBirth}
                    {...params}
                    onInput={(e) => {
                      const regex =
                        /^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
                      console.log(e.target.value);
                      e.target.value = regex.test(e.target.value)
                        ? e.target.value
                        : "";
                    }}
                 
                  />
```

Comment: When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb. Maybe it'd make more sense to either (a) validate on complete entry, or (b) write a function that does partial validation based on what's entered so far.

Comment: @DaveNewton ++Kudos on hammer and thumb thing.